# How to write summation as matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, kronecker-product

I am new to Matrix. Let $(\tau_{nij})_{N\times N\times J}$
$(X_{nj})_{N\times J}$,
$(\gamma_{n jk})_{N\times J\times J}$,
$(\pi_{i n j})_{N\times N\times J}$ and
$(\alpha_{nj})_{N \times J}$,
$(D_n)_N$ be matrix.
How can I write the following summation in matrix form?
$X_{nj}-
\sum_{k=1}^J \gamma_{njk} \sum_{i=1}^N X_{ik} \frac{\pi_{i nk}}{1+\tau_{i nk}}-
\alpha_{nj} \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^N \tau_{n ij} \frac{\pi_{n ij} }{1+\tau_{n ij}}X_{nj}=\alpha_{nj} D_n$.

where $\tau_{nij}=\tau_{inj}$ .

Comment: Please can you say what are all these variables ? We dont even know if they are scalar or vectors and the dimensions of the vectors

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does one run into expressions like this while being ‘new to Matrix’?

Comment: ()××
  ()×
, ()××
, ()××
 and ()×
, ()
 are matrix.@Lelouch